# Can I run code for IBM blockchain platform on AWS Blockchain Manager

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

As I am sure many of you know that IBM Blockchain Platform has been closed since April '23. So if I have a GitHub repository that works on IBM Extension can I run the sam eon AWS Blockchain Manager or IBM support for hyperledger fabric ?

I downloaded ibm extension for vscode through GitHub, and followed the steps given in the repository but when running the contract file, the application is t running as it's supposed to

Comment: Can you complete your question?